# How to load multiple tables from Cassandra in parallel?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

Is it possible to load multiple tables from Cassandra in parallel into context?

I can do one at a time

```
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "words")
```

, but if I need to join 3 tables, do I have to load each of them serially?

Any *parallel* alternative would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a union, e.g.

```
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "words").union(sc.cassandraTable("test", "numbers"))
```

The subsequent RDD will be queried by partition, so should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just

- fork off some Akka threads to submit each job
- ensure each job doesn't have all the resources (e.g. three tables means a third of the RAM and cores)

Then they will run in parallel

Comment: Would you mind sharing a sample code for forking Akka threads? I can imagine how it'd look like, but need code to confirm my understanding.